# Error with Ajax to send Blob with JS FormData

Tags: php, ajax, audio, web-audio-api

```
var blob = new Blob(mp3Data, {type: "audio/mp3"});
var formData    = new FormData();
formData.append("file_data",blob);
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    method      : 'POST',
    data        : formData,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
}).done(function() {
    console.log('users saved!');   
});
```

While Reading the in upload.php it returns the empty array , not even displaying the name `file_data`. Post always returns **`[]`**.

Comment: Are you sure mp3data is not empty _before_ you store it in the blob ?

Comment: Yes i am sure it has data

Comment: Have you checked `$_FILES`?